# Select box styling issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i have this select box :

`<select class="slctbx condition-Combiner" onchange="updateConditionBuilder()" style="color: rgb(153, 153, 153);" disabled="disabled">`

and i am using :

`$('#rule-condition-listing tr:last-child .condition-Combiner').removeAttr("style","#999999").removeAttr("disabled","disabled");`

so it actually removes disabled attribute but not the color attribute

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[.css()](http://api.jquery.com/css/) - Get the value of a style property for the first element in the set of matched elements or set one or more CSS properties for every matched element.

```
$('#rule-condition-listing tr:last-child .condition-Combiner').
  css("color","#999999").
   removeAttr("disabled","disabled");
```

or

```
$('#rule-condition-listing tr:last-child .condition-Combiner').
  css("color","").
   removeAttr("disabled","disabled");
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to pass attribute name to `removeAttr()` *but* you are passing name with value which is **not correct syntax**, check syntax of `removeAttr()` [here](http://api.jquery.com/removeAttr/).  You can use [css()](http://api.jquery.com/css/) to set the color attribute.

```
$('#rule-condition-listing tr:last-child .condition-Combiner').css("color","").removeAttr("disabled","disabled");
```

*Instead of using removeAttr to enable the element you can also use use .attr('disabled', false);*

Answer (score 2):

As stated in the jquery Api documentations, the removeAttr - function only accepts 1 condition. so if you do something like

```
$('#rule-condition-listing tr:last-child .condition-Combiner').removeAttr("style","#999999").removeAttr("disabled","disabled");
```

it means that you remove the style on the element, and the '#999999' is discarded. Same goes for the disabled part.

I hope it helps.

Kind regards, Alex

Answer (score 2):

Don't mix attributes with Styling.

In Jquery you should use [.css()](http://api.jquery.com/css/) property to work with styling, So this should work

```
$('#rule-condition-listing tr:last-child .condition-Combiner').css("style","").removeAttr("disabled","disabled");
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

```
$('#rule-condition-listing tr:last-child .condition-Combiner').css("color","").removeAttr("disabled","disabled");
```